# Como evitar que o usuário acesse sem estar logado?

Tags: php, extjs-4

Estou desenvolvendo uma aplicação com ExtJS 4 e PHP. Meu problema é o seguinte: Como eu faço para que o usuário não consiga acessar uma página da aplicação sem estar logado? Já tentei de tudo (que conheço), mas é como se o HTML ignorasse a verificação que faço.

Página indexPrincipal:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML> 
 <?php
    include('connect.php');
    session_start();
    if (!$_SESSION['logado']){        
        header("Location: index.html");
        session_destroy();
    } 
?>   
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>SIG - Sistema Integrado de Gestão - EMCM/RN</title>
    <!-- <x-compile> -->
        <!-- <x-bootstrap> -->
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" href="resources/css/app.css">
            <script src="ext/ext-dev.js"></script>
            <script src="bootstrap.js"></script>
        <!-- </x-bootstrap> -->
        <script src="app.js"></script>
        <!--<script type="text/javascript" src="app/view/Login.js"></script>-->
    <!-- </x-compile> -->
</head>
<body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: Só uma dica: coloca um `die` ou `exit()` depois do `session_destroy`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Você não pode enviar cabeçalhos com a função [header()](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.header.php) depois de dar output de algum dado.
Para corrigir seu problema tente isto:

```
<?php
    include('connect.php');
    session_start();
    if (!isset($_SESSION['logado']) || $_SESSION['logado'] !== 1){        
        header("Location: index.html");
        session_destroy();
        exit;
    } 
?>   
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
<head>
</head><body>....</body></html>
```

Comment: Não deu certo, continua ignorando a verificação :(

Comment: Editei a resposta para adicionar uma checagem a mais e garantir que redirecione.

Comment: Nada ainda, cara :(

Comment: Cara, descobri o problema. Minha página estava em formato .html, por isso ele ignorava a verificação. Modifiquei para .php e deu certo. Obrigado pela ajuda!